# How do I allow users to select published content on the site to be displayed on their profile page?

Tags: views, users, nodes

I would like to have published content on my site which a user can select if he/she would like for it to be displayed within a block on their profile page.

For instance:

- Published content is an article with image and body,
- When the user is viewing this node there is a checkbox (or whatever that will work) that will say "Add To Profile".
- If selected, then the content teaser will appear within a block on that specific users profile page.

I know how to get content that is created by a user to appear on that users profile, but I have been having difficulty getting this right.

PS: I know very little php, but know my way around Drupal.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into the [Flag Module](http://drupal.org/project/flag).  It provides links on nodes that allow them to be tagged/flagged. Then, with Views, you can create a block that will be displayed on user profiles with content flagged by that user.  In fact, it comes prepackaged with a "bookmarks" view that might be a good starting point for this.

Comment: Thank you Jimajamma, I achieved what was needed using your suggest of the flag module.

Answer (score 0):

- Add an entity reference field to their profile page
- In Views create view that will show content based on field from previous point
- Use [Viewfield](https://drupal.org/project/viewfield) to attach views to user profile page and to give uid back to views

It will not be a block, but it should work and you can template it to look like one.

Comment: I know there is at least one valid answer that will give a real block, I've seen something like that done. I just don't remember how. If no one will post it by the time I'll be able to recall it, I'll post it.